# Rewrite variable values based on another variable of same df

Tags: python, r, dataframe

Let´s say I have a dataframe, df.
This df has 3 columns: Names, D and R.

Now, R has been filled with a constant value for each name, but only accordingly to the maximum value that D has.
The problem is that *this is not the case*: variable R actually depends on the value that D has, and as I said, the existing value of R is only correct for the highest number of D for each name.

I want to decrease the value of R depending on the value of D *for each name*. To be more precise, each time D decreases by -200 (these are mts, but it´s not important), R has to decrease by -0.1. This functional relation applies to each and every name: the only relevant fact according to names is that each names has it´s own "starting point" for R.

```r
      Names     D      R
1    Group1    3290   1.4
2    Group2    3129   1.6
3    Group1    2920   1.4
4    Group4    1100   1.9
5    Group1    3500   1.4
6    Group1    3323   1.4
...
```

As you can see, the value of R is constant for each group, even though D is changing. Let´s say 3500 is the highest value for Group1. Then, I would expect something like:

```r
      Names     D      R
1    Group1    3290   1.3
2    Group2    3129   1.6
3    Group1    2920   1.2
4    Group4    1100   1.9
5    Group1    3500   1.4
6    Group1    3323   1.4
...
```

I already coded a solution for this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(R = case_when(
(Names=="Group1" & D>=3500-100) ~ 1.4
(Names=="Group1" & D<3500-100) ~ 1.3
(Names=="Group1" & D<3500-200) ~ 1.2
...
(Names=="GroupN" & D>=#highest_value-100) ~ #default_value_of_R_for_GroupN
...
))
```

But this is not elegant. That´s why I tried another solution like:

```r
library(sqldf)
list_Names <- sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT NAMES FROM df")
n<-1
while (n<30) {#here, 30 is arbitrary
decrement = n*200
  for (r in df$R) {
    for (n in list_names) {
      if (df$names[r]==n & df$D<max(df$D) - decrem) {
        r = (r - n*0.1)
  }}}
n = n+1
}
```

But that doesn´t go anywhere :/

I know there is a  much simpler way to proceed here. Any help (R or Python) would be highly appreciated!!!

P.D: the default values for R are not necessarily the max values, I have them in an Excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think with `dplyr`, you can do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Names) %>% mutate(R1 = R - (0.1 * floor((max(D) - D)/200)))

#  Names      D     R    R1
#  <fct>  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Group1  3290   1.4  1.30
#2 Group2  3129   1.6  1.6 
#3 Group1  2920   1.4  1.2 
#4 Group4  1100   1.9  1.9 
#5 Group1  3500   1.4  1.4 
#6 Group1  3323   1.4  1.4
```

which in base R would be

```
df$R1 <- with(df, R - (0.1 * floor((ave(D, Names, FUN = max) - D)/200)))
```

Comment: Beautiful, concise and elegant. Worked out perfectly.